# Cannot read barcode produced by ZPL Code 39

Tags: barcode, zpl

I am trying to print a barcode (code 39) to a label (2" x .75") on a Zebra ZT610 (600 DPI) printer, but none of our 3 barcode scanners will decode the barcode. We are encoding a 14-character alphanumeric value.  I created the label using ZebraDesigner, and passed the ZPL to the printer using Zebra Setup Utilities. I also use Labelary to check the label, and change parameter values.

I have tried every conceivable combination of the ^BY and ^B3 commands I can think of, that would fit on the label, including shortening the data for testing (encode only 8 characters).   Here is the latest ZPL with a barcode that should be well within the label's printable area, but scanners will not read it:

^XA~JSN^LT0^MNM^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR2,2~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
^XA^MMT^PW1200^LL0449^LS0^XZ
^XA^BY4,3,143^FT82,192^B3N,N,,N,N
^FD2116A83034137M^FS
^FT39,258^AAN,45,25^FH^FD2116A83034137M^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ

Unreadable label image:

[image]

We also have an old Zebra R110Xi4 (203 DPI) printer that we also print code 39 barcodes to, on the same labels.  The barcodes on these labels are perfectly readable by the scanners.  This is the ZPL for it:

^XA~JSN^LT0^MNM^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR8,8~SD30^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
^XA^MMT^LL0102^PW379^LS0^XZ
^XA^BY1,3,40^FT50,54^B3N,N,,N,N
^FD2116A83034137M^FS
^FT0,73^ABN,11,7
^FD2116A83034137M^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ

Are there any suggestions as to what I might try next?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post an image of a label with an unreadable barcode?

Comment: I added an image of a typical label we use.  The barcode is unreadable in the ZT610 printer, but is readable in the older Zebra R110Xi4 printer, with the ZPL modification to ^BY noted in my post.

Comment: So on further testing, I increased the module width to ^BY5,3 but cut the number of characters in half, i.e., 7 characters instead of 14, and sent it to the printer.  That barcode was readable!  So, it appears that the 600 dpi printer needs a BY5 module width.  However, we need to encode 14 characters, and that extends the barcode beyond the width of the label (2").  Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Do you have to use code39?  It is a low density 1D barcode.  For example, code128 typically encodes the same data in significantly less space.  Plus it has a built-in check digit, which code39 does not.

Comment: I agree with @MarkWarren: Code39 is often not readable on physical media because the bars are so tightly pressed together. Same issue with inkjet based output, where bleeding is a factor. Choose an interleaved code (2of5, code128 or a databar variant), these use the space much better.

Comment: Mark and MyICQ, thank  you for that suggestion.  Unfortunately at my workplace all the scanners are set up to use the Code 39, and they have a custom app.  It would probably be easier for us to use a wider label for one printer, and use the BY5,3 setting.  If  you guys think that would work.  I did try the JM setting with 'B' instead of 'A', and the barcode is 'intermittently' readable with that setting, but of course that's not acceptable either.